# Debugging NASM local labels with gdb

Tags: debugging, gdb, x86-64, nasm, dwarf

I have been having some issues debugging code assembled by `nasm` with `gdb`: it seems like `gdb` doesn't do well with `nasm` [local labels](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.15.05/html/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.9). `nasm` generates a local symbol named «function».label, which seems to confuse gdb, as it loses track of which function it is in.

Here is one scenario in which it gives a sub-optimal debugging experience:

```
section .text

global _start

_start:
  call foo
  ud2

foo:
  push rbp
  mov rbp, rsp
  call bar
.end:
  pop rbp
  ret

bar:
  ret
```

Compile and debug:

```
$ nasm -f elf64 -g -F DWARF example.asm -o example.o
$ ld example.o -o example
$ gdb ./example
```

```
Reading symbols from ./example...done.
(gdb) b foo
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400087: file example.asm, line 10.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/mvanotti/orga2/gdb/example 

Breakpoint 1, foo () at example.asm:10
10        push rbp
(gdb) ni
11        mov rbp, rsp
(gdb) ni
12        call bar
(gdb) ni

Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
_start () at example.asm:7
7         ud2
```

As you can see, `nexti` continues execution even after the return from the `bar` function call. I believe this is caused because the next instruction in `foo` belongs to the `foo.end` symbol, causing gdb to not recognize that as the return point of the function. Adding any other instruction before the `.end` label in the asm file fixes the issue.

Similarly, the backtrace gets all messed up when it steps into a local label:

```
(gdb) 
foo.end () at example.asm:14
14        pop rbp
(gdb) bt
#0  foo.end () at example.asm:14
#1  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

This also affects `yasm` and `lldb`.

There is not a clear workaround for this. I couldn't find an option in `nasm` to not emit the `function.label` symbols, or an easy way to remove them. `strip` for example, lets you specify the `--wildcard` option, but the regexp syntax is too basic and cannot match something like `.+\.*`. The closest I got was `strip --wildcard -N "*.*"`, but that also matches `.something`

In `gas`, this is solved by creating a label in the form of `.Llocal_label$` which gets discarded automatically by `ld`.

Comment: Note: I am assuming the `foo.end` thing is confusing gdb's `nexti` and `finish` commands: any pointer to the gdb code to confirm this would be appreciated!

Comment: Stepping over calls with `nexti` might(?) depend on `global bar:function` or something?  IDK, I usually use GDB with `layout reg` so I can see the actual asm.  NASM's extra symbols aren't a big problem because you're not depending on the current function name to keep track of where you are.

Comment: Have you tried using NASM with the default STABS debug format?  Its DWARF support sometimes makes a mess (e.g. a whole block of instructions don't get disassembled in GDB's `disas` or `layout asm` / `layout reg` mode).  I've never gotten around to reporting this bug to GDB or NASM. :/

Comment: Hi Peter! Good to see you again :). DWARF always gave me better debugging experience with gdb than STABS, that's why I use it (do you think stabs is better?). For example, when I set a breakpoint in foo with stabs, it skips the preamble. I have tried this example with STABS and I get the same behavior, `nexti` would not stop in the next instruction after the call.

Comment: The people from #gdb in freenode pointed me to this function: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=gdb/infrun.c;h=2c31cf452b10752508561051fcd6490c554a0721;hb=HEAD#l6994 it seems like it is using frame information to determine the call site and where to put the breakpoint.

Comment: After doing some debugging with `set debug infrun 1` and `set debug frame 1`, I checked that a step-resume breakpoint is inserted in the correct place, and the code stops in the right pc, however, somehow it decides to ignore that breakpoint. One of the differences is that the frame-id is different upon hitting the breakpoint. I still couldn't find the code used to match the frame.

Comment: I don't tend to write multiple functions in hand-written asm, usually just a performance experiment / microbenchmark in a single file (or a code-golf or SIMD thing I'm working on), so I don't make much use GDB features beyond stepi, and often end up copy/pasting a numeric address from disassembly to set a breakpoint with `b *0x...`.  None of this depends on debug info at all.  I haven't tried `finish` or `nexti` recently.

Comment: @Marco the code that checks the breakpoint frame is: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=gdb/breakpoint.c;h=16cf7977b62a41ea04858c4b7488a1a6986f0aaf;hb=HEAD#l5301

Comment: I see. Thanks, Andrew. The people from #gdb said that the frame checking is there to avoid recursion: you don't want your nexti to stop in the pc if it is in an inner frame. So that makes sense. I think it would be better if the check checked only "frame depth" and not "frame id". But it all goes back to gcc mixing up frames due to nasm special use of local labels.

Comment: Created a question in [the nasm forums](https://forum.nasm.us/index.php?topic=2754.0) to see what's their take on this.